# NetCore 3.1 Use IdentityServer4 with existing database and Users table

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an existing database with a table called Users (its actually an old  DotNetNuke 8.1 (like around 2016) database table structure with Users, UserRoles, etc tables).
It does not follow the structure of the current Microsoft Identity such as (AspNetUsers, AspNetUserRoles...etc).

I want to add an authentication layer into the NetCore 3.1 project that uses this database.
I managed to scaffold the database tables into models and add a db context classes, so I can access the Users table.

How can I add IdentityServer4 for Authentication with the usernames and their passwprds from the Users table.This is what I have so far:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
              
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            // added for identity server
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configurations.Configuration.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Configurations.Configuration.GetClients())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, Configurations.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, Configurations.ProfileService>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

          
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            // added for identity server
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            //added
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //added
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Test}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

The Configuration class for IdentityServer4:

```
public static class Configuration
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis() =>
            new List<ApiResource> 
            { 
                new ApiResource("ApiOne")  // registering one api with this name
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>    // define a client that will consume above api
            new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "resClient",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("topsecret".ToSha256()) },   // make client secret more complex for production, can be made to expire


                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,    // how client will request the access token

                    //define what the access token will be allowed to be used for, the scopes
                    AllowedScopes = { "ApiOne" }     // this client will be allowed to access Api One
                }
            };


    }
```

The ProfileService class:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            context.IssuedClaims = context.Subject.Claims.ToList();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

I try with a username and pass from the db (not hashed, its just for testing) but the return is always:

> "unauthorized_client"

[image]

Comment: At this point your IdentityServer4 Configuration is not working fine. Thats why you are getting an unauthorized_client error. And how is your project structure like?

Do you have ID4 in another project?

Comment: @Ismail Umar I only created this net core project so far that i want to serve as the identity server. So planning to use this net core web project for future client authentications. Trying to move away from the 4 year old DNN authentication and constraint, to upgrade the website built in DNN by moving parts to more modern net core services.

Comment: usually what I will do is put ID4 in another project in the same solution and have it deploy to another system/uri. Moreso, Can you move the ID4 to another project and test that separately before adding to your project. I will post an answer with a configuration I am currently using and I hope that works for U.

Comment: @Ismail Umar, not sure I understand. Can’t this be the separate project you are mentioning?

Comment: What I am saying is, you should first configure ID4 in another project and test your implementation. See that the solution is working fine before adding your DNN project users.

Comment: @ismail Umar, oh you mean “ApiOne” should be a separate client project maybe... but the what goes in the Identity Server 4 project? Actually I just read what you said while writing this. Not sure how to separate them. Not sure what goes in the ID4 and how ti

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219310/discussion-between-ismail-umar-and-razvan-emil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the config file you need to get IdentityServer4 working in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and above. Create a static class and wire it up in UR startup class like you have done

```
public static class InMemoryConfiguration
     {
          public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources()
          {
               return new[] {
                    new ApiResource("yourapp", "Your App", new List<string>() {"role"})
                    {
                         ApiSecrets = { new Secret("topsecret".Sha256()) },
                         UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Email, JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Name, JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, JwtClaimTypes.GivenName }
                    }
               };
          }

      public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
      {
           return new List<IdentityResource>
           {
               new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
               new IdentityResources.Profile(),
               new IdentityResources.Email(),
               new IdentityResource("roles", "Your App Roles", new List<string>() {"role"})
           };
      }

      public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients()
      {
           return new[] {
                new Client
                {
                     ClientId = "resClient",
                     ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("topsecret".Sha256()) },
                     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                     AllowedScopes = new [] { "yourapp" },
                     AllowedCorsOrigins = new [] {"http://localhost:8841", "http://localhost:8842"}
                },
                new Client
                {
                     ClientId = "mykabapp_native",
                     ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("mykabsecret".Sha256()) },
                     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                     AllowedScopes = {
                          StandardScopes.OpenId,
                          StandardScopes.Profile,
                          StandardScopes.Email,
                          "mykabapp",
                          "roles"
                      },
                     AllowedCorsOrigins = new [] {"http://localhost:8841", "http://localhost:8842"}
                }
        };
      }

      public static IEnumerable<TestUser> Users()
      {
           return new[] {
                new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId = "012345",
                    Username = "mail@userdomain.com",
                    Password = "password"
                },
                new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId = "123456",
                    Username = "admin@userdomain.com",
                    Password = "password"
                }
           };
      }
 }
```

---

// AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,

Pay attention to the line above. its really important and even if your client ID is correct on the client side. You can get the "unauthorized_client" error

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `unauthorized_client` client because `resClient` is configured to only accept the `ClientCredentials` grant you need to modify the client to accept the `Password` grant as well (or just Password if ClientCredentials are not required by this client):

```
                new Client
            {
                ClientId = "resClient",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("topsecret".ToSha256()) },   // make client secret more complex for production, can be made to expire


                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,    // how client will request the access token

                //define what the access token will be allowed to be used for, the scopes
                AllowedScopes = { "ApiOne" }     // this client will be allowed to access Api One
            }
```

To solve your `invalid_scope` error:

Replace call to `.AddInMemoryApiResources(Configurations.Configuration.GetApis())` with `.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configurations.Configuration.GetApis())` and change `GetApis()` to:

```
        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApis() =>
        new List<ApiScope> 
        { 
            new ApiScope("ApiOne")  // registering one api with this name
        };
```

Comment: Tried now I get, "invalid_scope"

Comment: Can you attach IdentityServer's log or console output?  There will be extra details in that log

Comment: here it is:

IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultResourceValidator: Error: Scope ApiOne not found in store.
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator: Error: Invalid scopes requested, {
  "ClientId": "resClient",
  "GrantType": "password",
  "Raw": {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "s2",
    "password": "***REDACTED***",
    "client_id": "resClient",
    "client_secret": "***REDACTED***",
   
}

Comment: "scope": "ApiOne"
  }